# Como criar verificação que validará se o ReportViewer está instalado?

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso criar uma verificação que validará a instalação do Report Viewer na máquina do usuário. Caso não esteja instalado, preciso receber essa informação para fazer um tratamento apresentar uma mensagem para o usuário e facilitar a manutenção futura.

Estou fazendo diversas pesquisas, porém, não estou tendo resultado.

Alguém sabe me dizer como posso criar essa verificação, ou tem algum conteúdo para indicar onde possa consultar?

Comment: É ASP.NET ou é WinForms? Não use tags de tecnologias que você não está utilizando.

Comment: @jbueno é WinForms no caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode verificar no registro:

```
public bool IsInstalled()
{
    RegistryKey registryBase = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, string.Empty);
    if (registryBase != null)
    {
        return registryBase.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v2.0.50727") != null
            || registryBase.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ReportViewer v10") != null
            || registryBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v10.0") != null;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Denis, vou implementar o código disponibilizado e ver quais resultados me retorna.

Comment: Implementei o código e fiz o teste, e esta retornando false. Nessa caso não existe ReportViewer instalado correto ? Percebi que a versão do meu Framework é diferente da que está no código, isso interfere na verificação ?

Comment: Denis, consegui resolver deu certo. Obrigado